# array adapter is showing field value, not data values from database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to show a `listview` of data from database in `fragments`. For that reason I've added a table in database. Now I'm trying to create data adapter. Here is my **code**:

```
list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
try{
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
List<Label> allLabel = db.getAllLabels();
for (Label label : allLabel) {   
ArrayAdapter<Label> dataadapter= new ArrayAdapter<Label>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,allLabel);   
list.setAdapter(dataadapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v, int position,long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ((TextView)v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is my output of containing field value not data value:

```
   com.qcash.atmlocator.Label@52852d88
   com.qcash.atmlocator.Label@52852dd8
   com.qcash.atmlocator.Label@52852e08
   com.qcash.atmlocator.Label@52852e38
```

this is the getAllLabels() function used in my code:

```
public List<Label> getAllLabels(){

List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<Label>();

// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        label.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        label.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(2));
        label.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(3));
        labels.add(label);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// closing connection
cursor.close();
db.close();

// returning lables
return labels;
}
```

How can I get the database value? please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding cursor data to a string and adding that string to the calling function fragment solved that. Here is the code:

```
 String name=cursor.getString(0)+"\n"+cursor.getString(1)+"\n"+cursor.getString(2)+"\n"+cursor.getString(3);
                FindPeopleFragment.ArrayofName.add(name);
```

Finally showing that array to adapter completes that:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ArrayofName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString() method in **Label** class. I am assuming that you class has a variable 'name'.

```
class Label{
   // other variables. 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Change the onItemclick listener

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v, int position,long id)
    {
        Label label = (Label)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + label.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: that I did in my Label class.